# I want to remove multiple line of text on linux

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

Just like this.

Before:

```
1
19:22
abcde

2
19:23

3
19:24
abbff

4
19:25
abbc
```

After:

```
1
19:22
abcde

3
19:24
abbff

4
19:25
abbc
```

I want remove the section having no alphabet like section 2.
I think that I should use perl or sed. But I don't know how to do.
I tried like this. But it didn't work.

```
sed 's/[0-9]\n[0-9]\n%s\n//'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new/ on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/[[:alpha:]]/' file
1
19:22
abcde

3
19:24
abbff

4
19:25
abbc
```

The above is simply this:

- `RS=` tells awk the input records are separated by blank lines.
- `ORS='\n\n'` tells awk the output records must also be separated by blank lines.
- `/[[:alpha:]]/` searches for and prints records that contain alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 4):

Simple enough in Perl. The secret is to put Perl in "paragraph mode" by setting the input record separator (`$/`) to an empty string. Then we only print records if they contain a letter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Paragraph mode
local $/ = '';

# Read from STDIN a record (i.e. paragraph) at a time
while (<>) {
  # Only print records that include a letter
  print if /[a-z]/i;
}
```

This is written as a Unix filter, i.e. it reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT`. So if it's in a file called `filter`, you can call it like this:

```
$ filter < your_input_file > your_output_file
```

Alternatively this is a simple command line script in Perl (`-00` is the command line option to put Perl into paragraph mode):

```
$ perl -00 -ne'print if /[a-z]/' < your_input_file > your_output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's exactly one blank line after each paragraph you can use a long `awk` oneliner (three patterns, so probably not a oneliner actually):

```
$ echo '1
19:22
abcde

2
19:23

3
19:24
abbff

4
19:25
abbc
' |  awk '/[^[:space:]]/ { accum = accum $0 "\n" } /^[[:space:]]*$/ { if(on) print accum $0; on = 0; accum = "" } /[[:alpha:]]/ { on =  1 }'
1
19:22
abcde

3
19:24
abbff

4
19:25
abbc
```

The idea is to accumulate non-blank lines, setting flag once an alphabetical character found, and on a blank input line, flush the whole accumulated paragraph if that flag is set, reset accum to empty string and reset flag to zero.

(Note that if the last line of input is not necessarily empty you might need to add an `END` block that checks if currently there's a paragraph unflushed and flush it as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/^$/M!ba};/[[:alpha:]]/!d' file
```

Gather up lines delimited by an empty line or end-of-file and delete the latest collection if it does not contain an alpha character.

This presupposes that the file format is fixed as in the example. To be more accurate use:

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;/^$/M!ba};/^[1-9][0-9]*\n[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\n[[:alpha:]]+\n?$/!d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution of [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362559/8344060) but with the following assumptions:

- The text blocks consist of 2 or 3 lines.
- If there is a third line, it contains characters from any alphabet.

In essence, under these conditions we only need to check for a third field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=;ORS="\n\n";FS="\n"}(NF<3)' file
```

or similar without `BEGIN`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F '\n' '(NF<3)' file
```